# Convert text to elements in XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm currently migrating XML from one CMS to another and needs to convert some text to elements. Because of how the system works, some editors can only enter escaped text. The challange is to replace some of these escaped elements and convert them into valid XML elements.

**Source file:**

```
<p>Press the &lt;button-name&gt;Select key &lt;/button-name&gt;to show more information.</p>
<p>Press the &lt;button-name&gt;Back key&lt;/button-name&gt; to save the 
values.</p>
<p>When the storage is completed, the &lt;product-name/&gt; machine
displays:</p>
<p>&lt;attention&gt;
&lt;display-text translate="no"&gt;STORAGE COMPLETED
Press BACK to exit&lt;/display-text&gt;
&lt;/attention&gt;</p>
```

**What I want to do**

```
 Replace &lt;button-name&gt; with <gui>
 Replace &lt;button-name&gt; with <kt.in name="custom-name"/>
 Keeping other escaped elements.
```

**XML I want**

```
<p>Press the <gui>Select key</gui>to 
   show more information.</p>
<p>Press the <gui>Back key</gui> 
   to save the calibrations values.</p>
<p>When the storage is completed, the <kt.in name="custom-name"/> machine
   displays:</p>
<p>&lt;attention&gt; &lt;display-text translate="no"&gt;STORAGE COMPLETED 
 Press BACK to exit&lt;/display-text&gt;
&lt;/attention&gt;</p>
```

I tried using a string-based search-and-replace but as I want proper an XML element as output this wouldn't do it.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? In my view the right way is to use extension to parse the contents of `p` elements and then to apply-templates to the parsed nodes and to transform as needed and to serialize back (for `attention`). However whether that approach is possible depends on the XSLT processor used and whether there are extensions available or implementable for parsing and serialization.

Comment: I'm using Xalan via AntillesXML. The parsing-all-then-serialize-back was a good idea. Ill try that out!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only going to work by string-based-search-and-replace - depending on the amount of text "tags" you want to switch to xml. The bigger problem I see is actually keeping it all in a proper XML-Element.

I dont think that you could keep this without writing a small tool that will read the strings between the elements of the text e.g.

```
&lt;button-name&gt;
```

and copy them into the right variables of an Object which you then parse back as XML conform Element.

It doesnt really depend on the language you prefer since there should be plenty of [object-xml parsers available](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/file-input-output-tutorials/4062-how-parse-object-xml-using-jaxb.html)

For just changing the tags you could also switch the encoding of the text as

```
&lt; would turn into -> <
```

and then filter any content in between the <> to exchange the ones you want e.g. button-name to gui

hope I could give you an idea..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was a bit unclear about the processor/language. I was hoping I could use a templatebased XSLt solution.